# Grouping c++ structs according to certain attribute

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a vector of structs.

```
struct info
{
    propertyX x;
    propertyY y;
    propertyZ z;
};

std::vector<info> infos;
```

The objective is to break up this vector into smaller vectors based on a condition.
The condition could be to group all infos that have the same propertyX value together or group all infos that have the same propertyY and propertyZ (pair) together.

I am thinking of creating a map with key being some kind of a hash of the properties to be considered and value to be a vector of info.

Is there a better solution that can be used here?

Comment: Do you mean you want to reorganize the vector's ordering or you want to extract another (sub)vector from the original one ?

Comment: Yes, I want to extract sub-vectors from the original one. 
If the list had 5 items - {(x1,y1,z1),(x1,y2,z1),(x1,y1,z2),(x1,y2,z2),(x1,y1,z3)}

The criterias to considered for grouping were propertyX and propertyY , the expected result would contain 2 vectors -
{(x1,y1,z1),(x1,y1,z2),(x1,y1,z3)}
{(x1,y2,z1),(x1,y2,z2)}

Comment: You can also sort `infos` by providing a suitable comparator, which will "group" elements together. This may be more efficient, at least from some perspective. Maps have a relatively large overhead due to dynamic memory allocations.

Comment: @Daniel Langr : I don't understand how sorting the vector will group elements. Could you elaborate a bit on this?

Comment: @ijaySha Sorting with a proper comparator will put all elements with the same key next to each other in the original vector. Then, it is trivial to put all "groups" into separate vectors, if that is even needed. Or, you can leave them in the original vector and just build some index structure above it.

Comment: @Daniel Langr : So the comparator could accept 2 info objects that needs to be compared based on the criterias required maybe in a format like (1,0,1) to mean consider only propertyX and propertyZ. The components of the struct are not exactly comparable, you could check whether they are equal or not. How can this information be used to sort.

Comment: Do you want to create new vectors, or just auxiliary structures that point to the initial vector ?

Comment: Create new vectors.